# Como deixar de rastrear alterações em um arquivo após o commit?

Tags: git

Eu tenho um arquivo `.properties` já commitado e gostaria de deixar de rastrear as mudanças feitas nele. Cada usuário que clonar o projeto irá configurá-lo da sua maneira.

Tentei esse comando:

```
git rm --cached application/src/main/resources/props/services.properties
```

Não me retorna nenhuma mensagem de erro ou sucesso, não sei se deveria também.

Mas mesmo assim, após esse comando, se eu fizer qualquer alteração no arquivo o git encontra a diferença e lista o arquivo como modificado. No que estou errando?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está no caminho certo. O problema é que apenas remover o arquivo não vai fazer com que o git pare de rastrear modificações.

Processo inteiro:

1. `git rm --cached`
2. Adicione o arquivo em questão ao `.gitignore`
3. `git commit`

Com isso você remove o arquivo e para de rastrear novas modificações. O `commit` é necessário para efetivar as operações.